# type out timer in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Hi I have created the below time out function that runs either 2 seconds after the person  has finished typing or on pressing enter. It works as described but for some reason i get the function repeating. For instance if i type 5 letter and wait 5 2 seconds i get 5 alerts after two seconds. I want just to receive 1 alert. What do i need to change?

```
function doSearch()
  {

  //run js function half a second after typing has stopped
  var typingTimer;  //timer identifier
  var doneTypingInterval = 2000; 

  $(document).keypress(function(e){
    $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            alert("pressesd");
        }
    });


    //on keyup, start the countdown
    $('#txtSearch').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
    });


    //user is "finished typing," do somethin
    function doneTyping() 
    {
    alert("done");
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    }


}
```

Thank s in advance

Comment: Please add a `jQuery` tag to your post since you're using it in your code.

Comment: @Axel Amthor In the JS specs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout

Comment: Why do you use nested `keypress` listeners?

Comment: I have not defined clearTimeout(.. as after reading this post i thought it was a defined function http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: Added Jquery as a Tag

Comment: I have nested listeners as later I am going to extend this to listen to other fields when this works. For nor I am just trying a basic function. I have removed the listener and the issue is still their

Comment: Removed nested listener and edited post so that code is clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the keypress event in document.ready

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
    var typingTimer = null;  //timer identifier
    var doneTypingInterval = 2000;
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#txtSearch').keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                doneTyping();
            }
            else {
                if (typingTimer != null)
                    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, 5000);
            }
        });
    });

    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        alert("done");            
    } 

</script>
```

Comment: Thats great. My function called off the text box was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you have several syntax errors in your script. Altered code:

```
var typingTimer;  //timer identifier

function doSearch()
  {

  //run js function half a second after typing has stopped
  var doneTypingInterval = 2000; 

      //on keyup, start the countdown
   $('#txtSearch').keyup(function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13)
       {
           clearTimeout(typingTimer);
           alert("pressesd");
       }
       else
       {
           clearTimeout(typingTimer);
           typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
       }
     });
   }

    //user is "finished typing," do somethin
    function doneTyping() 
    {
    alert("done");
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    }
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dr9pacm1/2/).

Edited the fiddle, **now** it really works :/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `keyup` event to clear the event, use `keypress` event instead.

```
var el = document.getElementById('input');
var timeOutId;

el.addEventListener('keypress', onKeyPress);

function onKeyPress(event){

    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        doStuff();
        return;
    }
    clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    timeOutId = setTimeout(doStuff, 2000);
}

function doStuff(){

    console.log('Doing Stuff');

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a1jc3fzj/)